# jquery variable: selection order doesn't update

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

It's considered best practise, according to Learning jQuery, to save common selections using variables, as it can save time and resources and help avoid errors through repetition.  A good thing when there are lots of elements and you're doing a lot with jquery.  But, the ordering of these variables doesn't get updated, which diminishes their usefulness.

Consider the following simple example.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

  var $elements = $('tbody tr');

  function dump_colours($selection){
   $selection.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).index(), $(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
   });
  }

  // Re-arrange the table.  Maybe during a sort.
  var $green = $elements.eq(1);
  $('tbody tr').eq(1).remove();
  $('tbody').append($green);

  dump_colours($elements);

  // $elements did get updated to some extent, but the ordering isn't right:
  console.log($elements.eq(1).text()); // Output: 1green10
  // Why isn't the ordering updated? $elements.eq(1) should be blue now.

  // It re-orders if we re-declare the variable.
  var $sorted_elements = $('tbody tr');
  console.log($sorted_elements.eq(1).text()); // Output: 1blue10
  // eq(1) now correctly selects the blue row.

  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>type</th>
    <th>colour</th>
    <th>cost</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>red</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class="foo"><td>1</td><td>green</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>blue</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class="foo"><td>1</td><td>yellow</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>orange</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>black</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class="foo"><td>1</td><td>white</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>purple</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>brown</td><td>30</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>pink</td><td>20</td></tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here, the selection $elements is updated to some extent, because the console.log() output shows the green row to have the updated index after the table is re-arranged.  It goes from index=1 to index=9.  But, the jquery ordering (for lack of a better term) isn't updated.  The method .eq() selects the wrong row.

Is there a good way to reconcile this in the spirit of using best practice, ie. better than constantly re-setting the jquery variable after every sort operation?  I've already tripped up several times by not using the same selectors consistently. This is one of the big advantages of using variables to store common things, to avoid unnecessary repetition and resulting errors.

**Edit: partial solution.**

Seems like there's no ideal solution when requiring jquery.

Scimonster posted a way that at least prevents mistakes occurring, but I found a much simpler solution for that by just storing the selector strings themselves:

```
var tr_selector = "div#table1 tbody > tr.discounted";

$(tr_selector).each(function(){
   ...
});
$(tr_selector).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't any way. I previously [asked about this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/live-element-lists) on jQuery's forum, and was told 'no'.

jakecigar there left a semi-solution, but it just abstracts away the calling:

```
$.liveList = function(selector) {
      return function(){ return $(selector) }
}
var TRs =$.liveList('tr');
TRs().css('color','green')
```

If you're not married to jQuery, you might also want to look at using plain DOM functions that return a [live NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#A_.22live.22_collection), which is the kind of thing you really want.